# Nested html table export to excel using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

```
<table id="prnttable" class="prnttable" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr><th>Head 1</th><th>Head 2</th><th>Head 3</th><th>Head 4</th><th>Head 5</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>ASD</td>
            <td>BSD</td>
            <td>ESD</td>
            <td>
                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th align="left">Sub Head 1</th>
                            <th align="left">Sub Head 2</th>
                            <th align="left">Sub Head 3</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>

                        <tr>
                            <td>AAA</td>
                            <td>BBB</td>
                            <td>CCC</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>AAA 1</td>
                            <td>BBB 1</td>
                            <td>CCC 1</td>
                        </tr>

                    </tbody>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td>WWW</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Excel
My Jquery

```
$("#btnExport").click(function (e) {
    $(".prnttable").table2excel({
        filename: "Report.xls"
    });
});
```

I try to export this table format to excel, But nested table out put going wired, any way to export this table to correct format.
any one help me please
any solution for this

Comment: The plugin doesn't have many options, mainly just a exclude option. So you will need to alter the source code of the plugin or write your own implementation. What is the output you are expecting?

Comment: I expected out put same like html table view.(https://www.screencast.com/t/6huiuccCg)